# How to synchronise two overlapping JavaScript onclick events

Tags: javascript, html

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a0bwouev/3/

My website has two "layers":

1. a language interface layer (English and French) where users can navigate the site in their preferred language. This wraps around the site content:
2. a content layer, where the user can view a selected Latin document in one of two formats: Interpretive or Diplomatic.

The language selection is controlled by the user clicking on:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav en-fr">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <span class="nav-link" id="selectEN" onclick="showEN()">EN</span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <span class="nav-link" id="selectFR" onclick="showFR()">FR</span>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Which relates to javascript:

```
    function showEN() {
    $( ".en" ).css( "display", "inline" );
    $( ".fr" ).css( "display", "none" );
    };

    function showFR() {
    $( ".en" ).css( "display", "none" );
    $( ".fr" ).css( "display", "inline" );
    };
```

The Latin view selection is more of a problem, because I need to toggle between language/document view selections for the title.

I have four possible title variations on title, where `diplo`= diplomatic and `inter` = interpretive

```
<h4 class="en inter">Latin - Interpretive</h4>
<h4 class="en diplo">Latin - Diplomatic</h4>
<h4 class="fr inter">Latin - Interprétative</h4>
<h4 class="fr diplo">Latin - Diplomatique</h4>
```

And then two related `<div>` containing the text in different Latin formats:

```
<div class="inter">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum cursus enim vitae condimentum ullamcorper. Nam tincidunt sagittis elit, eu sollicitudin diam sollicitudin pulvinar. Fusce sodales, lectus eu ullamcorper rutrum, lorem tortor auctor justo, vitae tempor augue metus ac nisl.</p> 
</div>
<div class="diplo">
  <p><span class="lin">[1]</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum cursus enim vitae condimentum ullamcorper.</p>
  <p><span class="lin">[2]</span> Nam tincidunt sagittis elit, eu sollicitudin diam sollicitudin pulvinar.</p>
  <p><span class="lin">[3]</span> Fusce sodales, lectus eu ullamcorper rutrum, lorem tortor auctor justo, vitae tempor augue metus ac nisl.</p> 
</div>
```

Two links for toggling between views `diplo` and `inter`:

```
<span class="diplo en" onclick="showInterpretive()">view interpretive</span>
<span class="inter en" onclick="showDiplomatic()">view diplomatic</span>
<span class="diplo fr" onclick="showInterpretive()">voir interprétative</span>
<span class="inter fr" onclick="showDiplomatic()">voir diplomatique</span>
```

Which relates to javascript:

```
    function showDiplomatic() {
    $( ".diplo" ).css( "display", "inline" );
    $( ".inter" ).css( "display", "none" );
    };

    function showInterpretive() {
    $( ".diplo" ).css( "display", "none" );
    $( ".inter" ).css( "display", "inline" );
    };
```

The initiating css for all of the above:

```
.inter     {display: inline;}
.diplo     {display: none;}

.en        {display: inline;}
.fr        {display: none;}
```

The problem is that toggling diplo / inter conflicts with en / fr. But I'm not sure how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to understand clearly, what you want is when the user selects french as language the formats should change to only show french version i.e.: <span class="diplo/inter fr" > ..</span> and hide the english formats?

Comment: personally I would just toggle classes on the body tag and have the css control it instead of selecting all the elements on the page.

Comment: Well you have the `diplo` and `inter` classes on the buttons.... seems like you need to remove that....

Comment: @epascarello Because I want to show / hide the respective buttons in context.

Comment: @BasharAliLabadi yes.

Comment: Would be better if you share a minimalistic basic fiddle.

Comment: Make a small sample that shows the problem. Use stackoverflow snipplet functionality.

Comment: Fiddle added to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the fiddle modified, does it accomplish what you want?

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/4ozycft7/1/)

what I did is that I added a variable to hold the language class name and in the view diplomat/inter I appended that variable to the CSS selector.

I also added the format to the state to track the format if the language changes to stay on the same format.

instead of:

```
$('.diplomat').display('inline');
```

I added:

```
$('.diplomat.'+ state.lang).display('inline');
```

where :

```
var state = { lang: 'en', format: 'i' }
```

and when the user changes the language we set the language in the state and in showFR/EN we check the format to keep the user choice.

that being said, you are not utilizing jquery power, there are better way to toggle stuff and since you are using jquery please use it to handle the click events instead of using `onclick` it should be very easy, read about it.

Disclaimer: The code in the fiddle can be cleaned up and improved I'm just trying to show the idea

Comment: Thanks for this. But it doesn't toggle the `div`s from `inter` to `diplo` when clicked. Also, when one clicks the languages, both titles show, which was my initial problem.

Comment: @jbrehr I have updated the snippet it doesn't show both formats now when language changes

Comment: and please note I didn't hide format divs initially I don't know what your application assumptions but if you want it's easy on document ready hide both divs

Comment: Thank you! But I have a question: when clicking `view diplomatic` / `view interpretive`, it should show/hide the related `div`. But it isn't in your example, even thought the divs carry `<div class="inter">` `<div class="diplo">`?

Comment: yes that's because they don't have the language class, I have updated the fiddle to show you how to fix that

Comment: Your update requires the Latin document to be output to a div for each language. That means 4 divs instead of 2. That's a lot of duplication of a large body of text...

Comment: but you actually have 4 documents not 2. However, if you expect the user to only choose one language then you can avoid loading the other language formats using ajax, but if the user toggled the language you will end up with 4 documents, on the browser. I just wanted to show you how to toggle the 2 x 2 layers, as I said you can optimize it as much as you need and based on your needs. best of luck !

Comment: There are 2 latin document views, each with a title variation in French and English. But you've given me the idea I need, thanks very much :)