# JavaScript functions don't fire off CSS updates and .getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009952/how-to-synchronise-two-overlapping-javascript-onclick-events) regarding toggling in JS, I've created a solution for the toggling show/hide of two `div` and updating different `span` texts from JS (fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/k5gbsxca/4/).

The problem is that NONE of javascript fires off, and I cannot identify why, when it uses functionality I've deployed before.

The javascript reacts to three different `onclick` events, all of which depend on reading and updating the variable:

```
var state = {
lang: "en",
latinview: "inter"
}
```

Functionality in the jsfiddle (using `switch` and `if`):

`onclick="changeDocView()"`

- depending on `state.latinview`: change button and `<h4>` text
- show/hide  `div class="document-inter"` and `div class="document-diplo"`

`onclick="showFrench()"`

- show `class="fr"`
- hide `class="en"`
- depending on `state.latinview`: change button and `<h4>` text

`onclick="showEnglish()"`

- show `class="en"`
- hide `class="fr"`
- depending on `state.latinview`: change button and `<h4>` text

The logic is exactly as I need it, and in components it works. But this is the first time I've tried to fire off actions based on testing a variable in JS.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you are mixing and matching jquery and your fiddle doesn't have jquery.

Comment: I'm still learning this stuff, including the jsfiddle.

Comment: @DanielA.White i don't think the only problem is jquery reference. if it was so, only code section where jquery methods used would cause error, but in this case, the error is "function is not defined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- add jquery library,
- in load type options, choose no wrap - bottom of head (on top of the script editor). default load type in jsfiddle is "On Load", and when "On Load" is chosen, your code wrapped in onload method, and js functions cannot be called from html. alternatively, you can set event functions in js like this,

`document.getElementById("idOfElement").onclick = function(){//do something}`

working code: https://jsfiddle.net/ercanpeker/exwkco2r/

Comment: Thank you! Question: would it be preferable to use the `document.getElementById("idOfElement").onclick = function(){//do something}`, or jquery `$( "#id" ).click(function()` in place of the `onclick=""` attribute in HTML?

Comment: jquery makes it easier and shorter, i think you should choose jquery one.